# emacs unexpected gt/lt behavior

Tags: c++, emacs, indentation

I am having problem with emacs indentation in c++

```
if (a.x < b ||
    a.x > c) {
    lll = 1;
}
```

is indented as

```
if (a.x < b ||
          a.x > c) {
    lll = 1;
}
```

Apparently it treats it as a template parameter. It is not happening if a is not a structure, say if (x < 10 || x > 20) works as expected.

It is minor but annoying thing. My emacs version is 23.

Comment: I tried pasting this code into Emacs 25, and it seems to indent correctly.

Comment: @legoscia Thank you I verified it. Unfortunately, installing a different version of just to address this issue is not viable. I will live with it, unless there is some lisp tweak I can apply.

Comment: You could try dropping a more up-to-date version of cc-mode.el into your installed emacs/lisp/progmodes directory (backing up the original first, of course).

Comment: @user888379. It did the trick. I had installed cc-mode from sources and it resolved the problem. Thank you.